# How to download previously purchased iTunes songs

Tags: itunes

How do I download purchased songs to my PC?
I am missing songs from several albums.

I cannot get the album or individual songs to download.

Answer (score 1):

Go iTunes → Music → iTunes Store. Then you must see something like this on the right side:

[image]

Hit Purchased and you will see and be able to re-download your songs.

Answer (score 0):

The method already suggested is limited to downloading 250 songs at a time. The Purchased page in the iTunes Store isn’t the place to download your past purchases. Instead, go to Music: My Music and wait for everything to show up after logging in to the iTunes Store. After your music library have loaded, press Command–A, right-click, and choose Make available offline. This will fetch everything in one go..

Source: https://www.slightfuture.com/how-to/redownload-all-itunes-purchases.html